# Why code doesn't Go past the firevents ("Onchange") if popup comes after

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

[image]I am trying to enter value in the text box and then fire event "onchange", which works. But after that I get a popup and code doesnt move past the onchnage code, so I cant click on the 'ok' button of popup.

```
<INPUT onchange=javascript:AcctId_ONCHANGE(); id=debAcctId class=textfieldfont style="WIDTH: 150px" maxLength=16 name=nefrtg.debAcctId fdt="String" enabled>

<INPUT onclick="javascript:return nefrtg_det_ONCLICK14(this,this);" id=Go class=sbutton type=button value=Go name=Go ?>
```

Is there a way to click on that button on same line of code or is there any other method?

```
ie.Document.frames(0).frames(0).frames(0).Document.getElementById("debAcctId").Value = strDebAcc

ie.Document.frames(0).frames(0).frames(0).Document.getElementById("debAcctId").FireEvent ("onchange")

    While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
        If ie.Busy Then
            DoEvents
            hWND = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Message from webpage")
            If hWND <> 0 Then childHWND = FindWindowEx(hWND, ByVal 0&, "Button", "OK")
            If childHWND <> 0 Then SendMessage childHWND, BM_CLICK, 0, 0
        End If
    Wend
```

Comment: Not sure what kind of popup it is. Put the breakpoint and try to debug the code step by step. Check whether your code is finding the popup window or not. Also, try to press the Enter key using .Sendkeys to check whether it is closing the popup or not. If possible then try to post the picture of that popup. It can help to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: @ Deepak-MSFT I have added picture for the same...Code doesn't go past the 'onchange' code (it doesn't move to next line) that's the reason I am not able to dismiss the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub ClickOKButton() 
    Dim strScript As String, sFileName As String, wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strScript = "WScript.Sleep 5000" & vbCrLf & _
                "Dim wsh" & vbCrLf & _
                "Set wsh = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")" & vbCrLf & _
                "wsh.SendKeys ""{ENTER}""" & vbCrLf & _
                "Set wsh = Nothing"
    sFileName = wsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%") & "\zz_automation.vbs"
    Open sFileName For Output As #1
    Print #1, strScript
    Close #1
    wsh.Run """" & sFileName & """"
    Set wsh = Nothing
End Sub
```

I ran above script before firing 'onchange'. It works but I am still looking for better answer for above issue.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your VBA code gets stuck when Alert message gets displayed on the page.

I tried to find a solution or a workaround but did not get any working examples.

I found in one old thread that user needs to create an instance of IE from another workbook and find the msg window and close it. I personally think that it is not a practical solution. Other than that I did not get any solution for VBA.

In further search, I found that if you are available to use the Selenium web driver to automate the IE browser then there is a solution for this issue.

**To click on the 'OK' button of the alert using Selenium:**

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

**To click on the 'Cancel' button of the alert using Selenium:**

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

Reference:

[Alert & Popup Window Handling in Selenium WebDriver](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html)

So you can think about this approach as an alternative for your VBA approach.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I understand and know about Selenium solution, but what I need is through IE. The above code runs on already logged in web page. I get its instance using 'Shell'. I have some ideas ...like can we do it using vbs?

Comment: I have found a workaround with vbs but I will wait for few days for the solution where I don't need to run another script, after that I will post my own answer here.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about your workaround and about the progress of this issue.